# Input value not set to 1 in edge browser(89)

Tags: javascript

In the google chrome browser back button detected and url change to home but same code not working for the edge browser.

```
<form>    
    <input id="backbuttonstate" name="backbuttonstate" type="text" value="0" style="display:none;" />
    </form>
    
        onload=function()
        {
            var e=document.getElementById("backbuttonstate");
            if(e.value=="0") {
                   e.value="1";
            }
            else{ 
             window.location = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/home';
            }
        }
```

Comment: Possibly a CORS issue, try with a relative address `/home`.

Comment: @Teemu, not working, try with alert also but alert also not working in else.